# Generating a path between two sets of pixel coordinates (x, y)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, path, coordinates, bezier

I have two sets of xy coordinates, start and end. The start is where I'd like to move from, and the end is the destination.

The goal is to produce an array of xy objects between the two coordinates that can be iterated over to produce a smooth, non-jumpy path to the destination, as shown below.

[image]

I've done reading around Bezier curves, but I'm struggling to visualise the implementation and wanted to know if there's an easier way to solve the above?

Comment: Do you want the curve to have some type of slope? If not solving for `y = mx + b` should suffice

Comment: Some form of angled slope is required in this instance, though y = mx + b is definitely sufficient enough if it wasn't.

Comment: What is defining the curb? If you only have two points, there is no way to apply Bezier or other spline mechanics, and get a non-straight line. You need at least one more parameter, like a third point. But even with just 3 points, you could just find the circle that is defined by those three points, and generate its arc. For more bending, you would need a fourth point, ...

Comment: If you want a slope I would do what @trincot says. Pick some third point that is not co-linear to the first two then pick your favorite regression technique to get the line

Comment: The important question that your post does not answer is _why_ it needs to be a curve. I.E. what additional information do you have that you're not telling, that justifies drawing a curve here, rather than a straight line? Because that's a "non-jumpy path" and conforms to everything else you're described so far.

Comment: The end goal is smooth object movements along a curved path (for simulation purposes) that's dynamically generated from start & end bounds. The only output required from the algorithm is an array of points to loop over for movement (this is handled already with mock data) - there is no drawing or anti-aliasing required. I'm now aware I'll need to randomly produce a few control points based off those random bounds, preferably sourced by the distance between the points for realism.

Answer (score 2):

For a bezier curve, I have adapted an algorithm from Maxim Shemanarev (see https://web.archive.org/web/20190307062751/http://antigrain.com:80/research/adaptive_bezier/ ) which involves establishing a tolerance by which to recursively break down the curve into linear segments.  By using a tolerance, the flatter parts of the bezier curve produce very few line segments, and for sharp bends of a bezier curve, the number of line segments increases in order to properly depict the curve.

Maxim Shemanarev's algorithm used the distance between the end points (P1 & P4) and the bezier control points (P2 & P3) as a means of determining whether the subdivided segment was sufficiently within tolerance, or whether the curve needed further subdividing.

I found, though, that his algorithm was unnecessarily complex when taking into account edge cases where the bezier included a very sharp curve.  My adaptation, to simplify his algorithm, includes the tolerance check for the distance between the line formed by the end points (P1 & P4) with the calculated midpoint (P1234).  By adding this tolerance check, any sharp bend that still exists between the end points will trigger a further subdivision into smaller line segments...

The javascript implementation is as follows...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>

<script>

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

function distanceSqr(v, w) {
  return (v.x - w.x) ** 2 + (v.y - w.y) ** 2;
};

function distanceToSegmentSqr(v, w, p) {
  var vwLength = distanceSqr(v, w);
  if (vwLength === 0) return distanceSqr(p, v);
  var t = ((p.x - v.x) * (w.x - v.x) + (p.y - v.y) * (w.y - v.y)) / vwLength;
  t = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, t));
  return distanceSqr(p, { x: v.x + t * (w.x - v.x), y: v.y + t * (w.y - v.y) });
};

function lineateBezier( bezierTolerance, p1, p2, p3, p4 ) {

  let tolerance = bezierTolerance * bezierTolerance;
  var result = [ p1 ];
  
  function recurse( p1, p2, p3, p4 ) {
    
    var p12 = { x: (p1.x + p2.x) / 2, y: (p1.y + p2.y) / 2 };
    var p23 = { x: (p2.x + p3.x) / 2, y: (p2.y + p3.y) / 2 };
    var p34 = { x: (p3.x + p4.x) / 2, y: (p3.y + p4.y) / 2 };
    var p123 = { x: (p12.x + p23.x) / 2, y: (p12.y + p23.y) / 2 };
    var p234 = { x: (p23.x + p34.x) / 2, y: (p23.y + p34.y) / 2 };
    var p1234 = { x: (p123.x + p234.x) / 2, y: (p123.y + p234.y) / 2 };

    if( distanceToSegmentSqr( p1, p4, p2 ) < tolerance &&
        distanceToSegmentSqr( p1, p4, p3 ) < tolerance &&
        distanceToSegmentSqr( p1, p4, p1234 ) < tolerance )
    {
      result.push( p1234 );
    } else {
      recurse( p1, p12, p123, p1234 );
      recurse( p1234, p234, p34, p4 );
    }
  };
  
  recurse (p1, p2 || p1, p3 || p4, p4);
  result.push( p4 );
     
  return result;
};

function draw( bezierTolerance, startEndPoint, startControlPoint, endControlPoint, endPoint, clearCanvasFlag, pointsFlag, controlFlag ) {

  // Get line segment points 
  let lineSegments = lineateBezier( bezierTolerance, startEndPoint, startControlPoint, endControlPoint, endPoint );

  // Clear canvas
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  if ( clearCanvasFlag ) {
    ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
  }

  // Draw line segments 
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo( lineSegments[ 0 ].x, lineSegments[ 0 ].y );
  for ( let i = 1; i < lineSegments.length; i++ ) {
    ctx.lineTo( lineSegments[ i ].x, lineSegments[ i ].y );
  }
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
  ctx.stroke();
  
  // Draw points
  if ( pointsFlag ) {
    for ( let i = 0; i < lineSegments.length; i++ ) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc( lineSegments[ i ].x, lineSegments[ i ].y, 1.5, 0, 2 * Math.PI );
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
      ctx.stroke();
    }        
  }
  
  // Draw control points...
  if ( controlFlag ) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo( startEndPoint.x, startEndPoint.y );
    ctx.lineTo( startControlPoint.x, startControlPoint.y );
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#0000ff';
    ctx.stroke();
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo( endPoint.x, endPoint.y );
    ctx.lineTo( endControlPoint.x, endControlPoint.y );
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  
}

draw( 1,  { x:35, y: 45 }, { x: 65, y: 45 }, { x: 60, y: 110 }, { x:90, y:110 }, true, true, true );
draw( 5, { x:135, y: 45 }, { x: 165, y: 45 }, { x: 160, y: 110 }, { x:190, y:110 }, false, true, true );

draw( 0.25, { x:20, y: 200 }, { x: 250, y: 290 }, { x: 250, y: 160 }, { x:20, y:250 }, false, true, true );

</script>

</body></html>
```

Please note the critical variable `bezierTolerance`.  In running the example above, the top curve on the left uses a `bezierTolerance = 1`, which means that as long as the distance between the end points (P1 & P4) relative to P2, P3, and P1234 is less than 1, then the segment is sufficiently "curved", and therefore no further subdividing occurs.

As a comparison, the top curve on the right uses a `bezierTolerance = 5`.  Again, any bezier subdivision in which the distances from the line segment formed by P1 and P4 to each of the points P2, P3, and P1234, are all less than 5 will qualify as sufficiently "curved", and be added as a line segment to the results.

As an extreme example, the curve on the bottom includes a very sharp bend.  By setting `bezierTolerance = 0.25`, you will note that the algorithm handles the sharp bend gracefully by including additional subdivisions to better represent the curve...

In short, a high tolerance will produce less line segments and a less than optimal bezier curve when drawn, and a low tolerance will produce more line segments and a better looking bezier curve.  But, a tolerance way too small will produce a result with an unnecessary number of line segments, so some experimentation is required to establish a well balanced `bezierTolerance`...

Answer (score 1):

The math for a cubic Bezier curve boils down to a single equation ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Cubic_B%C3%A9zier_curves)):

[image]

The implementation of that equation in pseudo-code looks like this:

```
let p1 be the start point
let c1 be the first control point
let c2 be the second control point
let p2 be the end point

for (i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
{
   t = i / 20.0;
   s = 1.0 - t;
   x = s*s*s*p1.x + 3*s*s*t*c1.x + 3*s*t*t*c2.x + t*t*t*p2.x;
   y = s*s*s*p1.y + 3*s*s*t*c1.y + 3*s*t*t*c2.y + t*t*t*p2.y;
   output point(x,y)
}
```

Here's a sample output with the control points positioned to give a gentle curve:

[image]

The start point is the black dot, and the first control point is at the end of the black line. The end point is green, and the second control point is at the end of the green line. Note that the control point determines the initial direction away from the start/end point. The distance from the start/end point to the corresponding control point can be thought of as the initial speed. Using a moderate speed will yield points on the curve that are approximately evenly spaced (shown in the image above).

Using speeds that are fast or slow will result in unevenly spaced points on the curve. For example, in the image below, black has a high initial speed, and green has a low initial speed, resulting in the points being bunched near the green point.

[image]

If both speeds are fast, the points get bunched in the middle. If both speeds are slow, the points are bunched at the start/end, and spread out in the middle. So there is a sweet spot where the initial speeds are equal, and just right to keep the dots evenly spaced.

Answer (score 0):

You have two sets of points so a stright line can fit into it. In which case you can use the straight line equation: `y = mx + b`; where `m` is the slope and `b` the y-intercept.

```
const coord1 = [2, 5];
const coord2 = [4, 7];

function generatePath(arr1, arr2) {
    const m = (arr2[1] - arr1[1]) / (arr2[0] - arr1[0]);
    const b = arr1[1] - m*arr1[0];
    let lineArray = [];

    for(let x=arr1[0]; x<arr2[0]; x++) {
        let y = m*x + b;
        lineArray.push([x,y]);
    }

    return lineArray;
}
```

This assumes the two coordinates in a two element array, and returns an array of arrays which contains coordinates with the x value getting incremented by one, but the increment could be any fraction as well.

Comment: This is great to see visualised - thanks, however, ideally having some form of control point to angle the path to the destination point is unfortunately needed. It's what I'm finding difficult to implement the most right now.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean. Do you want the line to be a curve instead?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
/*
you can pass an equation of the form y = a * x^2 + b * x + c (parabola) between the points
the equation has 3 unknowns a, b, and c. to get those apply the conditions: when x = 35, y = 45 (start) and when x = 90, y = 110 (end).
the problem is that you can't solve for 3 unknowns with just 2 equations
to get a third equation assume that at the midpoint, where x = (35 + 90) / 2 = 62.5, y = 85
note: if we were passing a straight line between start and end, the y coordinate of the midpoint would be (45 + 110) / 2 = 77.5
so, anything greater (or less) than 77.5 would be OK
the 3 equations are:
35 * 35 * a + 35 * b + c = 45
90 * 90 * a + 90 * a + c = 110
62.5 * 62.5 * a + 62.5 * b + c = 85
you can use Cramer's rule to get the solution to these equations
to get the 4 determinants needed you can use 
*/
const determinant = arr => arr.length === 1 ? arr[0][0] : arr[0].reduce((sum, v, i) => sum + v * (-1) ** i * determinant(arr.slice(1).map(x => x.filter((_, j) => i !== j))), 0);
```