# How to find midpoint of an array of points and continue recursive call till a number of times?

Tags: javascript

The idea is to find the mid point of a bezeir curve. Following is the De Casteljau's algorithm for finding the midpoint of a curve with four points.

How can I implement such an algorithm in javascript using recursion?

Following is the four starting points. From here we start the algorithm and through recursion we arrive the tip of the tree.

```
(0, 0)
      \
       (1/2, 0) --> this node is calculated as follows [(x1 + x2)/2, (y1 + y2)/2]
      /        \
(1, 0)          (3/4, 1/4)
      \        /          \
       (1, 1/2)            (3/4, 1/2)
      /        \          /
(1, 1)          (3/4, 3/4)
      \        /
       (1/2, 1)
      /
(0, 1)
```

for example the sample input of points will be like this

```
const points = [[0,2], [4,5], [6,7], [3,8]]

output = [3,5]

// so the output will be just an array of two numbers for eg: [3,5] (just a rough figure for demo) which represents the midpoint of the above four points obtained by the above algorithm.
```

So this tip of the tree (output) will be the midpoint of the given curve.

This is the code a fellow coder of stack overflow (Nina Scholz) have come up with and it works perfectly for me. But I want to extend it further. I've given an illustration. Nina's code is perfect for finding the midpoint for the first time. I want to find the remaining points by segmenting the curve as follows.

```
const
    getB = array => {
        if (array.length === 1) return array[0];

        const result = [];

        for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            result.push([(array[i - 1][0] + array[i][0]) / 2, (array[i - 1][1] + array[i][1]) / 2]);
        }        

        return getB(result);
    },
    points = [[0, 2], [4, 5], [6, 7], [3, 8]];

console.log(getB(points));
```

**UPDATE**

Remember each node is calculated as follows [(x1 + x2)/2, (y1 + y2)/2]. i.e., by taking the average of similar coordinates of two adjacent points.= .

**UPDATE**

The code suggested by Nina Scholz works fine.

But I want to extend it further. Ninas code returns the first midpoint. But I want to extend it to find more points as illustrated below.

[image]

**UPDATE**

This is not to segment the curve. But to find points at equal distance, by starting at the mid point then dividing the curve in to two segment, then again finding midpoint of those two segments, like wise this repeats till the number of points required is reached/exhausted. So the requirement is to find the points of a cubic bezeir curve.

**NOTE**

Once the middle point is returned this point becomes the starting point and ending point of the lines obtained by the previous midpoint, in this way it proceeds further till the number of points required is reached. This way we can find the location/coordinates of points separated by equal distance starting at the midpoint.

**JUST CONSIDER IT LIKE FOLDING A PAPER.** INSTEAD HERE WE FOLDS THE CURVE & finds the points of the curve at each fold/ points of segmentation.

Comment: Do you want to segment curve to `n` equal parts?
Do you require recursion?

Comment: Not to segment the curve. But to find points at equal distance, by starting at the mid point then dividing the curve in to two segment, then again finding midpoint of those two segments, like wise this repeats till the number of points required. So the requirement is to find the points of a cubic bezelr curve.. Please show me some code, so that I'll be able to direct!

Comment: when getB return the middle point, you will need to chunck your points in 2, adding middlePoint at the end of the first chunck, and at the beginning of the second chunk, and start again getB() on both those chunks. Repeat until you have enough middle points

Comment: Exactly. Tha's what I need. Yes. Thats right. Once the middle point is returned this point becomes the starting point and ending point of the lines obtained by the previous midpoint, in this way it proceeds further till the number of points required is reached.

Comment: Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Ivan_SD/vfz6aok1/33/)?

Comment: Yes @IvanDidyk. Exactly like that. But will I be able to get the coordinates of those points. Can you modify the function to return those divided points?

Comment: OK, made it. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Ivan_SD/vfz6aok1/74/), it is interactive (hover on point)

Comment: @mex, if "...the requirement is to find the points of a cubic bezeir curve", then take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60020136/generating-a-path-between-two-sets-of-pixel-coordinates-x-y/60021940#60021940.  Note that this doesn't provide equidistant points on a bezier curve, but rather, points that optimally define the curve to a specified threshold.